# HTTP Patch request using java

Tags: java, http

I need to send an HTTP Patch request using a Java program. Can someone post a code snippet displaying how to do this?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/REST-API-Integration/PATCH-example-with-apache-HttpClient/td-p/202197

Comment: Since 4.2, there is a [HttpPatch class](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPatch.html) available in Apache HttpClient

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you:

```
Response response = request(webTarget).method("PATCH", entity);
```